# Python DB fetched rows print as objects and not data

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle11g

I am starting with Python, and currently trying this basics:

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass@hostname/DBName')
cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
        select * from
        (select definition_code, content_data, creation_date
        from acms_content
        order by creation_date desc)
        where rownum <= 4
        """)
for column_1, column_2, column_3 in cursor:
    print ("Values:", column_1, column_2, column_3)


print (con.version)
con.close()
```

Now when I run it via python3.5 connect.py, I get:

```
Values: Something1 <cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x2aacb49c7a08> 2016-06-02 16:48:50    
Values: Something2 <cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x2aacb49c78f0> 2016-06-02 16:09:01    
Values: Something3 <cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x2aacb49c7a08> 2016-06-02 15:50:29    
Values: Something4 <cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x2aacb49c78f0> 2016-06-02 13:07:48    
Values: Something5 <cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x2aacb49c7998> 2016-06-02 09:39:46
```

Why is this happening? How do I print the value of that object?
I should mention that `content_data` column is `XMLTYPE` - basically in Oracle SQL Developer, double clicking on the cell, shows me the XML text inside. How do I do this with Python?

Also, this is just a precursor to some migration scripts I need to do (files, XMLs, DB entries) - so if you could recommend some good quick reads to write Python code correctly and efficiently debugging it, please post - I would love to read it.

Comment: I know this works with MySQL and I assume that it works with Oracle as well. Have you tried print ("Values:", str(column_1),str( column_2), str(column_3)). If you are looking for a way to parse the XML, take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: Doesnt work here, I still get those <cx_Oracle.OBJECT object at 0x2b4f4949aa08>

Comment: The documentation at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html deals with the same type of queries you are dealing with.